# ionic-native/in-app-browser - is it still relevant in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm getting an error that's coming up on InAppBrowser which is not letting me run my application. I installed the NPM and still the error is showing. Could it be that it's been removed from Ionic 4, if so which is the latest one to be used.

My `app.module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
    import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
    import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
    import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

    import {AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';
    import {AngularFireAuthModule} from 'angularfire2/auth';
    import {AngularFireDatabaseModule} from 'angularfire2/database';
    import {AngularFireStorageModule} from 'angularfire2/storage';
    import { HomeProvider } from './services/churchservice.service';
    import { ToastProvider } from './services/churchservice.service';
    import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
    import { HomePageModule } from './pages/home/home.module';
    import { PlansPageModule } from './pages/plans/plans.module';
    import { MorePageModule } from './pages/more/more.module';
    import { ReadPageModule } from './pages/read/read.module';
    import { SettingPageModule } from'./pages/setting/setting.module';
    import { YoutubeVideoPlayer } from '@ionic-native/youtube-video player';
    import { PayPal, PayPalPayment, PayPalConfiguration } from'@ionic native/paypal';
    import { SermonProvider } from './services/churchservice.service';
    import { MyDevotionsProvider } from './services/churchservice.service';
    import { MyEventsProvider } from './services/churchservice.service';
    import { MyBlogProvider } from './services/churchservice.service';
    import { MyAnnouncementsProvider } from './services/churchservice.service';
    import { MyVerseProvider } from './services/churchservice.service';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,


      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment),
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        AngularFireDatabaseModule,
        AngularFireStorageModule,
        HomePageModule,
        PlansPageModule,
        MorePageModule,
        ReadPageModule,
        SettingPageModule,
        HttpModule
      ],

      bootstrap: [],
      entryComponents: [
        AppComponent,

      ],
      providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorHandler },
        HomeProvider,
        ToastProvider,
        InAppBrowser,
        YoutubeVideoPlayer,
        PayPal,
        SermonProvider,
        MyDevotionsProvider,
        MyEventsProvider,
        MyBlogProvider,
        MyAnnouncementsProvider,
        MyVerseProvider,

      ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

I was upgrading Ionic 3 project to Ionic 4.

Comment: Could you share the error log ?

Comment: Type 'Observable<{ key: string; heading: "string"; authorname: "string"; date1: "string"; time: "string"; content: "string"; }[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Announcements[]>'.Type '{ key:string;heading:"string";authorname: "string"; date1: "string"; time: "string"; content: "string"; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Announcements[]'. Type '{ key: string; heading: "string"; authorname: "string"; date1: "string"; time: "string"; content: "string"; }' is not assignable to type 'Announcements'. Types of property 'key' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"string"'.

Comment: I can't see anything related to In App Browser in this. Seems to be a type mismatch. Am I missing something ?

Comment: i was able to fix it seemed like it wasn't communicating with the provider